# While-loop is not stopping in java

Tags: java

I'm using a stack that populates it with variables that are declared. It should pop every element in there until it reaches a **{** or **}**. However, when I use `stack.peek().equals("{")` or `stack.peek().equals("}")`, it doesn't become true.

I've used .peek() to see what was coming up and it does recognize "{" or "}".

```
while(!tempVariableStack.peek().toString().equals("}") || !tempVariableStack.peek().toString().equals("{"))
{
    System.out.println(variableStack.push(tempVariableStack.pop().toString()).toString());
}
```

[inside of stack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PuMyJ.jpg)

Despite the while loop, it continues to run through the while-loop.

Comment: one of the expressions will always be true. Try replacing `||` with `&&`

Comment: de Morgans Law will help you with this one. You ORed the expression which means if you get "}", the right expression will become !false which is true, which in turn makes the while loop go on forever. Change it to &&

Comment: Thank you it worked